# Proper headers for pseudo static JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, python-2.7, browser-cache

I have a python 2.7 app on Google Appengine.  One of the JS files is served via a python script, not a standard static handler. The app.yaml config is shown below:

```
- url: /js/foo.js
  script: python.js.write_javascript.app
  secure: optional
```

The request for foo.js is part of a code snippet clients, of our service, place on their website, so it can't really be updated.  python.js.write_javascript.app basically just reads in a JS template file, substitutes in a few customer specific values and prints to the browser.

What I'm wondering is, how do we set the correct headers so this request is cached correctly.  Without any custom headers, appengine's default is to tell the browser never to cache this.  This is obviously undesirable because it creates unnecessary load on our app.

Ideally, I would like to have browsers make a new request only when the template has been updated.  Another option would be to cache per session.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well

It looks like Google handles this automatically.  I just print it, using the correct JavaScript headers but without any cache headers and Google's CDN caches it for me.  I'm not sure what the default cache lifetime is but I saw no increase in instances or cost by implementing this.

It seems Google just takes care of it for me.